# Rotational invariance of the Lebesgue measure for a unit sphere for any metric.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, rotations, invariant-theory

Let $\rho(\cdot, \cdot)$ be any distance metric on the set $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ and let $S^N = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}: \rho(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{x}) = 1\}$ be the unit N-sphere.

For a fixed $k \in [0, 2]$, let $M(\bar{\mathbf{x}}) = \{\mathbf{x} \in S^N : \rho(\bar{\mathbf{x}}, \mathbf{x}) \leq k\} $ denote the set of points on the sphere $S^N$ that are within a distance of $k$ from the point $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$.

How do I rigorously show that $\lambda(M(\bar{\mathbf{x}}))$ = $\lambda(M(\bar{\mathbf{y}}))~\forall \bar{\mathbf{x}}, \bar{\mathbf{y}} \in S^N$? Here, $\lambda(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of its argument.

Is there a way I can define rotational invariance for the Lebesgue measure on an $N-$sphere for a given distance metric?

Comment: The "less than or equal" $\leq$ symbol is \leq . And I think you meant $\lambda(M(\overline{\bf x}))=\lambda(M(\overline{\bf y}))$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527754/rotation-invariance-of-the-lebesgue-measure

Comment: Aren't both measures just $0$?

Comment: @Ennar -- Yes, a sphere has $0$ volume... The set $M(\overline x)$ could be redefined as a subset of a ball, while $\overline x$ and $\overline y$ remain on the sphere.

Comment: @mr_e_man, well yeah, but this is basically asking for arc length (for the lack of better term when $N\neq 1$) which Lebesgue measure just doesn't provide. In case of $N = 1$ or $N = 3$ sphere has Lie group structure and one could use Haar measure, which is then rotationally invariant by definition.

Comment: @Ennar -- Where does arclength come from? The set $M(\overline x)$ would be a solid chunk of a ball.

Comment: @mr_e_man, the set $M(\bar x)$ is subset of $S^N$ and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{N+1}$. It could be solid chunk of a ball, but it's one dimension less than the space. It's like asking what's the area of a circle (not a disk, the boundary of a disk).

Comment: @Ennar -- Yes, the original question had $M$ part of a sphere. But I suggested to change it to a full-dimensional object so the measure is non-zero.

Comment: @mr_e_man, sure you suggested a correction, but the wording in OP is quite clear and it's definitely not what you suggest. My comment was addressed at that, not at what could work if we changed the question.

Comment: @mr_e_man : yes, I meant $ \lambda(M(\bar{\mathbf{x}})) = \lambda(M(\bar{\mathbf{y}})) $.

Comment: @Ennar: Intuitively, I mean the "surface area" of the N-sphere. How do I define the rotation operation for the N-sphere? Please help.

Comment: Ravi, I understand what you want, but Lebesgue measure won't give you that, it gives volume. It's like asking for the area of a line in a plane - it's zero. What you are asking is differential geometric notion, not measure theoretic one.

Comment: @Ennar Ohh I see. I understand. So what is mathematically the correct way to denote the "surface area/arc length" of N-spheres?

Comment: [This wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_area) might be a good starting point.

Comment: @Ennar Thank you for pointing me to that article. While I understand how to represent the "surface area" for the Euclidean distance metric, I do not know how to represent the "surface area" for any arbitrary distance metric $\rho$.